# Drawing disappears on minimize or resizing the window in MONO Cairo drawing

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I have a desktop application built on MONO. The Application has a button and a drawing area, on-click of the button it draws a house in the drawing area.. till here i don't have any problem but once i re size the window or minimize the window the drawing disappears.

Please let me know if any one came across this problem or if any one knows about it.

Thanks,

Best Regards,
Veeresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common "issue". It's not really an issue though, it's just the way things work. When you draw something to the screen it's just there in video card ram. When you minimise or move another window over it, something needs to redraw the image. In your case you have nothing to redraw it. You probably need to move your code to draw it to the paint event so that it paints it every time the window needs painting.

Another option would be to draw to a bitmap and display the bitmap in a image control but this is wasteful of memory. It can be the right choice in the correct situation.